# HTTP digest authentication for webdav and Office 2010 upload center

Tags: php, web-applications, webdav, office-2010

I have a web application that has a WebDav share for Word that uses http digest authentication. We use javascript like the following to open word documents on the  in word:

```
Doc = new ActiveXObject("Sharepoint.OpenDocuments.3");
Doc.EditDocument(url, 'Word.Document');
```

In office 2003 and office 2007, it works (but not 100% reliably). In Office 2010, I can open the document fine, but when I save a document, it comes up in Microsoft Office Upload Center, with the error "Upload Failed - Upload error". There is a drop down menu button offering to resolve the problem, but none of the options are useful in diagnosis.

Looking at the logs on the server, it got as far as making a LOCK request.

We are using a slightly customised version of [HTTP_WebDAV_Server](http://github.com/rjmunro/HTTP_WebDAV_Server/) from PEAR. Will we need to switch to a more advanced authentication for this to work? Can that be done from a PHP based WebDav server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a WebDAV server implementor, I know the PHP class is very simple, but it has a lot of gaps in functionality. I hope it's not considered spamming if I link you to my project, but [SabreDAV](http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/) has pretty good compatibility with most clients, it's a much larger project though.

Comment: I don't think it's spamming if you have had it working with Word 2010. If you haven't tried, then it's spamming :-)

We need to read the users from a DB and restrict them to certain actions in certain folders. Can this be set up with SabreDAV?

Comment: SabreDAV seemed to fix the problem for us, but it took a while because we needed to upgrade the PHP version to get it working. (That was month's ago, but I have forgotten to come back here and report my progress).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the similar issue, on the .Net tough.

I've actually made the LOCK and Word 2010 performed PUT of the document.

Did you tried to debug the DAV session using Fiddler? If you compare the results from Fiddler using your application and the SharePoint for the same document you might see some differences.